# Can I save thoughts I've encountered?

Tags: everything

While playing Everything, I came across a thought which I found particularly enlightening.

> Think of your many years of procrastination and how you've been granted more and more time of which you never took advantage. It's time to realize the nature of the world which you belong - to understand that you have a time limit and it's running out. So use it to advance your enlightenment or it will be gone forever.

I know that I can view a menu of my most recent thoughts by pressing <kbd>M</kbd>. However, I want to save or favorite this thought so that it doesn't get overwritten by thoughts I find later.

Is there any ingame way I can save a thought for future reading?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, no, thoughts will always be overwritten by newer thoughts or erased when you clear your mind. There is no way to pick and choose thoughts to keep.

Writing it down like you have would be the best way to remember inspirational or otherwise noteworthy thoughts like this one, but there is nothing in-game to keep them.